# Avoid Circular Reference

Tags: excel, formula, circular-reference

I am trying to program a counter in column E where if in cell F2=F1, increase the counter, otherwise reset the counter to 1, but I keep getting a circular reference error for that cell. This formula is placed in cell E2. The first value should be in cell E2 should be 1 because the value in cell F2 does equal the value in cell F1. How do I make this work without getting circular reference errors?

[image: Circular Reference]

Comment: Don't think you can with a formula, would need VBA.

Comment: You should not be getting a circular reference with that formula in that cell.  There must be more to this problem.

Comment: Your formula works perfect for me. There must be something else somewhere

Comment: No the formula works, I realized later on that there were other cells referencing themselves. I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your job list is sorted this formula works:

`=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)`

The important part is to fix the first part of the range to be filtered and the second part to be relative to the current position.

By that only the previous and current rows are filtered.
[image]

If the list isn't sorted, the formula still works - but in case 14625 occurs at the end of the list ist will count as 4.

Comment: I dont have excel 365 I only have 2016.

Comment: Too focused on FILTER - it works with COUNTIF as well - updated the answer

Comment: I still seem to be getting the circular referemce error.

Comment: If you are using it starting from `E2` to check column F it should be `=COUNTIF($F$2:F2,F2)` - then there can't be a circular reference

Comment: Im using this cell though to reference for array formulas found here https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match

Comment: you don't need an array formula - put the formula in E2 and drag down.